# can't find sp.runtime.js

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, people-picker, mvc

Trying to use a people picker in a sharepoint online MVC add in but when I try to import the javascript files needed I get "not found" error in the Error List.

This is how I try to import the files

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
```

I've read that the files should exist in "/program files/...../15/" but I don't have any js files in here.

I'm I missing a Nuget package or something?
I'm clueless bout what to do.

Also I'm adding jquery script in the bundles file but when I run my app and look in the console.log it says "SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: '$' is not defined" . Complaining about

```
$(document).ready(function () { initializePeoplePicker('pplPickerSingle', false, 'People Only', 44) });
```

Comment: have you referred clientpeoplepicker.js??

Comment: check this [Use the client-side People Picker control in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-the-client-side-people-picker-control-in-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-in).

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://anhvnn.wordpress.com/2017/08/29/sharepoint-online-create-your-own-client-people-picker-using-javascript/

Comment: <Sharepoint:ScriptLink> doen't seem to work in a sharepoint mvc add-in

Comment: Is this a provider hosted addin? Or a sharepoint hosted addin?

Comment: Provider hosted

Answer (score 0):

For Provider Hosted MVC add-in, please PnP Core.PeoplePicker Library, here is a complete code demo for your reference:

[People Picker MVC Sample](http://sharethefrustration.blogspot.com/2015/12/people-picker-mvc-sample-officedev-has.html)

ClientPeoplePicker usually used in SharePoint Hosted add-in, for Provider hosted app, use the PnP Core.PeoplePicker as suggested.